# SAS: Set default length for all character type data within a session

Tags: input, sas, character

Is there a way to override the default behavior of character length being set by the first value encountered and instead set all character data for a session to have the same fixed length?

---

Much of the data I work with daily is of a similar format/structure, such as a .csv or .txt.  I find that using an `infile` statement with list input works well for importing this kind of data.

For instance, suppose I have a text file `myData.txt`.

```
          myData.txt
string1 string2 num1 string3 num2
hello   there   12   this    33
is      some    45   sample  2
data    for     8    you     12
```

I would then use code like this to bring it in.

```
%let dataDirectory = C:\path\to\file;
%let dataFile      = myData.txt;

filename myFile "&dataDirectory.\&dataFile.";
data in_data;
  infile myFile dsd dlm = '09'x firstobs = 2;

  length
    string1 $ 50.
    string2 $ 50.
    num1      8
    string3 $ 50.
    num2      8
    ;

  input
    string1 $
    string2 $
    num1
    string3 $
    num2
    ;
run;
filename myFile clear;
```

I find that it is important to have the `length` statement so that none of my data is truncated.  Since the data sets are not particularly large, it makes sense to set all the character lengths to some fixed amount which will guarantee no truncation occurs.  I find that the default numeric length is sufficient.

The problem with this approach is that any time a variable name needs to be changed etc, I need to make an alteration in both the `length` and `input` statements.  This gets to be a nuisance, especially when there are 150 variables, and I'm hoping it is unnecessary.

List input seems appropriate to my needs.  I could use column input, but then I'd have to fiddle around with defining column widths.  I can't think of a way to make that a simple process when handling 150 columns.  Being able to globally define all character lengths, as with the default 8 for numeric, would solve my problem.  Is this possible?  Or, maybe you have a better method for bringing in such data as `myData.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a macro variable to store your default length. Then you can change it in one place.

You can use a variable list in your INPUT statement so that you don't need to worry about typing variable names more than once.

```
%let dataDirectory = C:\path\to\file;
%let dataFile      = myData.txt;
%let defLength = $80 ;

data in_data;
  infile "&dataDirectory/&dataFile" dsd dlm='09'x firstobs=2 truncover ;

  length
    string1 &defLength
    string2 &defLength
    num1      8
    string3 &defLength
    num2      8
  ;

  input (_all_) (:) ;
run;
```

Comment: This is great!  To be clear, is the `(:)` acting as an [input modifier][1] or as a wildcard?

[1]: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/n0lrz3gb7m9e4rn137op544ddg0v.htm#p1wk2kecsf6iz8n1ufug4i5pg6id

Comment: It is an input format modifier. You need to have an informat list inside the second (), but you don't want to list any actual informats since you don't really know what variables are in the (\_all_) list.

Comment: You could also use `+0` as the format list instead of `:`.  That says move the column position forward by zero columns. So it does nothing but satisfies the syntax structure of having a format list inside the second set of `()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your length statement in the proper order you can use a SAS variable list for the INPUT statement.  You don't need the $sign in the input statement.  If you have INFORMATS for some variable use an INFORMAT statement to associate.

```
data in_data;
  infile myFile dsd dlm = '09'x firstobs = 2;

  length
    string1 $ 50.
    string2 $ 50.
    num1      8
    string3 $ 50.
    num2      8
    ;

  input (string1--num2)(:);
run;
```

Comment: You can just use `input string1--num2;` or to make even easier use your construct with `_ALL_`.  Like `input (_all_)(:);`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how many rows SAS should use to determine field attributes with the "guessingrows" option using proc import. That way proc import will take care of any number of new variables you may have.

```
proc import out=importeddata
            datafile= "/examplepath/file.txt"
            dbms=dlm replace;
       delimiter='09'X;
       getnames=YES;
       guessingrows=5000;
run;
```